# Removing trailing slash from one specific directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to remove a trailing slash from all the url's in one specific (/blog) directory.

For example:

http://www.example.com/blog/cowboy/ should be 301ed to http://www.example.com/blog/cowboy
http://www.example.com/tips/cowboy/ should stay the same and NOT be 301ed

I currently use the following RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ index.php?m=pages&p=group&id=blogs_page [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?m=pages&p=group&id=blogs_page&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/?$ index.php?m=pages&p=$1 [L]
```

Can this reweriterule be modified that it removes the trailing slash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have `301` rule before existing rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(blog/.+)/$ /$1 [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteRule ^blog/?$ index.php?m=pages&p=group&id=blogs_page [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^blog/(\d+)/?$ index.php?m=pages&p=group&id=blogs_page&page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^blog/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?m=pages&p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```